# Is not surpported System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations in Uno platform?

Tags: uno-platform

`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` is not surpported in Droid, iOS, MacOS.

this is my model class but I can't use the `DataAnnotations` attributes.

How can I workaround this problem?

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class EquipmentType
{
    [MaxLength(50)]
    //[ForeignKey(TableName = "EquipmentCategory", ColumnName = "Code", Options = ForeignKeyOptions.Delete)]
    //[Binding]
    [Required]
    public string EquipmentCategoryCode { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required]
    //[Unique]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    //[Binding(Key = "EquipmentTypeName")]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: This namespace is not part of the WinRT contract: it's part of the _dotnet framework_ itself. So it should work unchanged, no matter the platform. Maybe you have missing the `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` clause in your code?

Comment: `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` Working Uno platform WASM, UWP but Droid, iOS, MacOS not working

Answer (score 3):

The attributes in this namespace are not available out of the box, but you can install the [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ComponentModel.Annotations/) that will add them:

```
<PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" Version="5.0.0" />
```

This package is compatible with all platforms Uno Platform targets. Unfortunately, it does not provide the classes you need on Android, iOS and macOS.

On these targets, within the platform projects you should find a **References** node. Right click and choose **Add reference**. In the dialog go to **Assemblies - Framework** and add the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`:

[image]

Comment: I also installed the Nuget Package.

`System.ComponentModel.Annotations Version 5.0` and `6.0`

There are no IntelliSense errors, but I get the error on build.

Comment: It is not built except by adding the source code directly from Github.

Comment: I have added a workaround, but it is curious the NuGet package approach does not work

Comment: i do install System.ComponentModel.Annotations Nuget Package but not add System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations reference.
this is my mistake so solved

Comment: Great, glad it helped :-) . Please consider accepting the answer so that the question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

i temporarily solved this problem

this is my best..

[image]